# OpenCV - Detection of rectangle or pentagon

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

How can I detect an rectangle or pentagon from an image using OpenCV? I have lot of  pictures of name card and I must detect their sides.The name card actually rectangle but sometimes name card corners cropped.I have tried `HoughLinesP()` function but it's just finding lines.

I must detect the shape above the picture, which means I need to detect the name card edges regardless of that shape rectangle or pentagon and need to crop only name card object from the Image.

[image]

---

Expected Result:

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: _"and its finding just lines"_ that is what Hough transform for lines is for. Please show a few images and some code, and see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps below:

1. Find the contours in the image using `findContours`.
2. Perform `approxPoly` to get the polygon shape of all the contours present in the image.
3. Check the approximated contour size (number of sides in the polygon):

   if the number of sides is **4 => Rectangle**

   if the number of sides is **5 => Pentagon**

The code is in python but should be easy to convert to C++:

```
import cv2

gray = cv2.imread('img.png',0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)

contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,1,2)

for cnt in contours:
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    if len(approx)==5:
        print "pentagon"
    elif len(approx)==4:
        print "rectangle"
```

Comment: This will work only for trivial images. But it's a start... ;D Can you post a snippet to show how to do it?

Comment: @Miki , i dont know what's a "trivial image " in your cases , if you have examples of images that it may not work for them, edit your question and link them.

Comment: It's not my question ;D

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [MatchShapes](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaadc90cb16e2362c9bd6e7363e6e4c317) function.

[Here is an example](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html).

I've also found a tutorial implementing an approach similar to what @Dr.Haimovitz suggested:
It's [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/).